# How to populate and sync the index with incremental changes from the data source?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, sql-server-2014, c#-5.0, azure-cognitive-search

I have data in an on-premise SQL Server 2014 database. I want to leverage Azure search to improvise the search capabilities of the application developed using angularjs (frontend) and Web API 2 (backend) hosted on premise environment. At present the search is done using SQL Server’s full-text search feature, but due to frequent performance issues, we want to leverage Azure Search.

I have data managed across across multiple table. I want to populate the index based on column-to-column mappings between the index and the various tables.

I referred to this article: http://gunnarpeipman.com/search2/azure-search-index/

Can anyone guide me to know the best approach to populate the index and also sync the index with incremental changes from the data source on a recurring schedule.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Azure Search SQL indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers)

One indexer can only index one table  or view.
To index multiple tables, probably the simplest approach is to create a view that joins tables and projects columns you want to index. Pay special attention to providing a "high water mark" column so you can use efficient incremental change detection (see the linked article for details).